# How to provide a singleton in a dagger module with 2 different implementations

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger, dagger-2

Imagine a dagger `module` that has the following two methods to provide an object.

```
@Provides @Singleton Cache<Settings> providesSettingsCache( Database db )
{
    return new StateCache( db, BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE );
}

@Provides @Singleton Cache<User> providesUserCache( Database db )
{
    return new StateCache( db, BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE );
}
```

In my example `StateCache` implements both the `Cache<User>` and the `Cache<Settings>` interface. Now instead of both methods returning an instance of `StateCache`, i'd like both methods to obviously point to the same instance.
How can this be achived in Dagger? Does the `module` hold a reference the one instance of `StateCache`, and have both methods return that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let Dagger manage the `StateCache` instance.

```
@Provides @Singleton StateCache provideStateCache(Database db) {
  return new StateCache(db, BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE);
}

@Provides @Singleton Cache<Settings> provideSettingsCache(StateCache cache) {
  return cache;
}

@Provides @Singleton Cache<User> provideSettingsCache(StateCache cache) {
  return cache;
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the response! Once you read the above snippet, the obvious suddenly makes sense.

Comment: Is `Singletony` (sic) a typo?